# Prevent Chrome Timers on Hidden Tabs Running at 1 Second Resolution

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, timer, webrtc

I read that timers on hidden tabs run with a resolution of 1 second. Thats realy a defect for me. With WebRTC browsers can build up a p2p network. For my application one of the peers functions as a server for the others. Now, if the peer whos the server hides his tab, all other clients suffer, because the server is running at 1 fps.

In my case the application is a game, and so thats not acceptable.
I think with the arising of WebRTC more applications will want to make use of this pattern.
Is there a solution for this problem?

If not google should fix this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize [Web Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/). They are unaffected by the state of the tab/window and you get minimal delay.

Here is [an example/time test](http://plnkr.co/edit/W3jfbb) of Web Workers + setInterval/setTimeout.
In the example I have a worker that sends a message to the main page every 200 milliseconds.

From my tests when the tab is hidden I get less than 0.5 milliseconds delay per call pretty much the same as active tabs.

Let me know if you want any clarification.